# How to capture the balance total of an initial investment on a year by year basis by use of a for or while loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am attempting a previous years exam paper in preparation for my own exam.

The question is as follows:

*Write a method to calculate and return the value of an investment in n years at the interest rate 7% a year. The method should have a real output type and two parameters, double invest and int n.*

I am able to produce the required variables and implement them either in a while loop or a for loop but I am unsure how to actually capture the first year investment total (1070), store it and actually add this to the following year investment total, and then so on?

I just require some pointers please in how to capture the first year total, then add to the second year, then the third year etc.

Here is my code:

```
public class Investment {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double investment = 1000;
    double interest = investment * 0.07;
    double balance = interest + investment;

    int years = 5;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        double totalBalance = balance + balance;
        count++;
        System.out.println("Your investment is: " + totalBalance
                + ". Years invested: " + count);

    }

}

}
```

Please forgive any errors in my code. I am still learning the Java syntax.

Thank you.

Comment: Why has the question been voted down? Is there a problem with the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do you really need loop?

how about :

```
balance = invest * Math.pow(1.07, n)
```

also you may want to use `BigDecimal` type instead of `double` to do currency calculation.

**EDIT**

(get the investment growth every year.)

I just read the exam question you quoted. it asked for a total balance, I therefor posted that line. if you need to get the growth data each year, you could write a loop, e.g.:

```
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
System.out.println(invest*0.7*Math.pow(1.07,i-1));
```

(codes are not written in IDE, could have typoes)

Comment: What if I wanted to display the investment growth on a year by year basis though?

Comment: Hmmm... Never used BigDecimal before. Lecturer has never mentioned it? Will research further. Thanks.

Comment: @PrimalScientist fyi, added the loop way to print growth of every year.

Comment: This is ACE!! Thanks Kent =]

Comment: @PrimalScientist well I don't know who gave you downvote. I don't think your question is poor, however it is not good enough to gain my upvote. sorry.

Comment: don't think the vote here too serious, it is sometimes strange. :) important is your problem gets solved.

Comment: Agreed =] I was just thinking this sort of thing makes you scared to ask a question though...